# Visual Studio not printing out directory name properly when run via command prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Disclaimer : Started this a few months back and now revisiting. Still not working much with Visual Studio and Windows API.

For the most part, the code works.

The issue is when an invalid directory reference is used, the directory string prints out incorrectly.

[image]

This is the line of code in question.

```
  _tprintf("Invalid Handle  %s   <DIR>\n", ffd.cFileName);
```

This was a sample found and wonder if it was run with some other version of Visual Studio/Windows or project setting.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t length_of_arg;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
        return (-1);
    }

    StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);

    if (length_of_arg > (MAX_PATH - 3))
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("\nDirectory path is too long.\n"));
        return (-1);
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("\nTarget directory is %s\n\n"), argv[1]);

    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
    {
        _tprintf("Invalid Handle  %s   <DIR>\n", ffd.cFileName);
        return dwError;
    }
    :
    ///Doing other stuff here....
    :    
    FindClose(hFind);
    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: Seeing "╠" back tells you what happened when you use the Debug build, the variable was never assigned.  At runtime, all variables are initialized to 0xcc thanks to the /RTC compile option.  Of course it wasn't assigned, FindFirstFile() failed.  You surely meant to use szDir instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I assumed the code was correct, but should have looked more closely. Thanks.